# I forwarded a domainand now I get error messages about the Google Api Key

Tags: api, dns, forwarding

We bought this domain http://deerrepellent.ca/ and forwarded it to our main site http://bobbex.ca

However now we get an error message saying we need a new google api key whenever anyone goes to new domain.  We do use maps in this site. Is there a way to use one API key for multiple domains?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you need to have one API key per domain.
The following blog post outlines a similar issue to yours and how the developer got around it/ They still needed to have two API keys, but using some JavaScript they were able to apply the correct key based upon the domain:

http://wave.coop/blog/2010/12/google-maps-api-keys-sites-multiple-domain-names/

Below is the official word on Google over multiple domains and API keys, as also referenced in the above blog post:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#multiplekeys